# Linear model in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, linear-regression, linear-algebra

I have some prepared dataframe :
Customer_Age    Customer_Gender count
0   17  M   846
1   17  F   460
2   18  M   970
3   18  F   790
4   19  M   1188
... ... ... ...
129 84  M   4
130 85  M   16
131 86  F   4
132 86  M   4
133 87  F   6

I want to create linear model and regression. This is my code:

````
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
select2 = df.groupby('Customer_Age')['Customer_Gender'].value_counts().rename('count').reset_index()
select2
x = select2['Customer_Age']
y = select2['count']
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x, y)
model = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)```

I get error:
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[number]
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before running the model add this line:

```
x = x.reshape(-1, 1)
```

Comment: x = x.reshape(-1, 1)
x = select2['Customer_Age']
y = select2['count']
model = LinearRegression() i get error AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape'

Comment: i addded x = select2['Customer_Age'].values.reshape(-1, 1) but i got nothing

Comment: If it is a series then change the code to: x = pd.DataFrame(select2['Customer_Age'])

Comment: ok i got scatter, but how i can add line to plot ?